# disable enter of two dots in UITextField

Tags: swift

necessary when entering into the UITextField from Decimal Pad keyboard:

1. replace the comma in the dot
2. disable enter of two dots

I did it, but these conditions are in conflict with each other:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 if string == "," {
   textField.text! += "."
   return false
 }

 let dotsCount = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
   if dotsCount > 0 && string == "." {
   return false
 }
 return true
}
```

Please help with the decision

Comment: What do you mean by introduction of two points? Avoiding that the string contains two dots?

Comment: I`am sorry.

yes, I want avoiding that the string contains two dots

Comment: But one dot will be ok?

Comment: You could replace double dots... like (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("..", withString: ".") would something like that solve your problem?

Comment: Would three dots be ok?

Comment: yes.
I entering data from the Decimal Pad keyboard in UITextField. By regional standards at me instead of dot - a comma. The data from the line, I'll convert to Double. so I need when entering data replace the comma in the dot and disable enter of two dots because it is a Double.

Comment: I need one dot only. more specifically disallow entry dot, if the string already contains the dot

Answer (score 3):

The decision was on the surface

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let dotsCount = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
    if dotsCount > 0 && (string == "." || string == ",") {
        return false
    }

    if string == "," {
        textField.text! += "."
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```